# Cassandra key space replication across nodes

Tags: cassandra

I am using Datastax Cassandra. I am creating key space with replication factor 3, so is there any way to determine on which 3 nodes this key space will get replicated?

Comment: In a way, yes, you can create custom key repartition, but it is not recommanded because there are already some good implementation.

Comment: If I want to check where replicated copies are getting stored. Where to look for this?

Comment: Where means on which nodes?

Comment: yeah I understood. Then you need to know a little bit about cassandra but it's no big deal.

Comment: (looking for a link to give you)

Comment: can't find a good link... There are some videos but you need to log in to have access.
In short, the row key is hashed, and depending on the value, it is send to a specific node (see the partitionner for that), then the SimpleStrategy will just take the next 2 nodes to store the replicas.

Comment: Ok i will look into it

Comment: If you want the tutorial, it's on https://academy.datastax.com/ . The course 201 details the data repartition

Comment: I am using default configuration of Cassandra. I am new to Cassandra, and I want to know how it actually doing this storage things.

Comment: then it's as simple as I described above. See @chaitan64arun for how to calculate the token from your keys and where the token will go. Then you just need to look on the next nodes to find the replicas

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you want to do that! But let me try to help.

To calculate this, you will need to know

- Total no of nodes in the cluster
- Replication factor
- Partitioner used
- No of vnodes

Please calculate the token range using
http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/1.2/cassandra/configuration/configGenTokens_c.html

Please calculate the token of your key. CQL has token function.
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/usePaging.html

Now you can map this number to the range you calculated before to know which physical node it belongs to.

Hope it helps!